# Facebook and Linkedin Redirect URL not working in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have an iOS project which has only a wkwebview. I try to load my web application in the webview. In the web application there is a feature to connect facebook and linkedin. This part is implemented in the web application and is working. By working I mean if I open my web application in desktop browser or in iPhone safari browser and try connecting the facebook and linkedin its working.

The problem I am facing is that when I try to connect the account through wkwebview its not working. The redirect URL is called with code and state(in case of linkedin) but there is a blank screen after successful authentication and it does not redirect back to the original page and there is no connection happening.

Inside the `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` I am intercepting the redirect URL and it has the code and state(linkedin) as expected. But somehow its not getting connected.

Other option is that, when we get code and state from the redirect URL intercept it and send a post request to fetch accesstoken and then call custom server api to save the accesstoken. But all this has been implemented in web application and I do not want to redo it.

What might be the problem that even after successful calling redirect url it not working.

Hope you understand the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    if ([navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"https://a.sitename.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"]) {
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = nil;
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
    }
    return decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your decidePolicyForNavigationAction code? Hard to understand the issue without seeing the code.

Comment: @Phyllis updated the question